How can (Why can't) I trace tracepoints with perf?
I would like to trace systemwide tracepoints. Perf list tells me that the following tracepoints are available:
  block:block_io_start                               [Tracepoint event]
  block:block_plug                                   [Tracepoint event]
  block:block_rq_complete                            [Tracepoint event]
  block:block_rq_error                               [Tracepoint event]
  block:block_rq_insert                              [Tracepoint event]
...
  power:cpu_frequency                                [Tracepoint event]
  power:cpu_frequency_limits                         [Tracepoint event]
  power:cpu_idle                                     [Tracepoint event]
  power:cpu_idle_miss                                [Tracepoint event]

I understand that I should trace the tracepoints with
 perf record -e TRACEPOINT -a

for a systemwide trace. However, I am told that the tracepoint is an unsupported tracepoint:
perf record -e block:block_io_start -a      
event syntax error: 'block:block_io_start'
                     \___ unsupported tracepoint

libtraceevent is necessary for tracepoint support
Run 'perf list' for a list of valid events

I installed all libtraceevent* pacakges. My kernel is:
6.8.0-45-generic #45~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Sep 11 15:25:05 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


You will likely have to rebuild perf with libtraceevent support. Depending on your system the process might include installing the linux-source package and possibly build-essential, and of course libtraceevent-dev. Then cd /usr/src/linux-source-…/tools/perf && make
It's hard to trace why perf is built without libtraceevent, but bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2019247 has some pointers, as does https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2076190
I'm eagerly waiting for the reintroduction of libtraceevent into perf in Ubuntu Noble, ref that last bug.

Thanks for the answer. Just a quick follow up: Uname show that I have  6.8.0-47-generic, which I don't see under linux-source. Linux-source in fact is linked to linux-source-5.15.0. Should I instead download the original 6.8.0-47 and compile perf from there or should I use the (mismatching) linux-source?
